# Deserializing JSON to .NET object with random class

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Как узнать к какому классу принадлежит объект myObject  и десерилизовать его с Json.net?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text) по документации

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObjectСlass>(text) так хотелось бы


JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeof(myObject)>(text) - Пробую так  ошибка!!!
```

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Если это ваш сервер отдаёт json - передавайте тип одним из полей (а во второе сам json в строку положите), если чужой - гипотетически можно попробовать десериализовать каждым классом, отлавливая эксепшены, на практике никто так не делает.

Comment: вот тут вроде вышло                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178323/json-net-deserialize-to-object-with-type-parameter